# SQL SERVER – Cannot resolve collation conflict for equal to operation

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

Coudl you please tell me wehre I should put `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`

to get the following view created?

I did search and found out that I should put each side of the where clause. I tried all possbilities but still I am getting the same error saying that 'Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.'

Here is the query :

```
CREATE view [dbo].[NewADUsers] AS SELECT 
tbl.objectGUID AS UserGUID 
, SUBSTRING(tbl.Email, CHARINDEX('@', tbl.Email)+1,
LEN(tbl.Email)- CHARINDEX('@',tbl.Email)) AS 'DomainName'
, gd.GroupName, dsg.DefaultSubGroup, tbl.sAMAccountName
, tbl.sAMAccountName AS UserName, tbl.Email AS Email
FROM (
SELECT  
"SAMAccountName" AS sAMAccountName, "mail" AS Email, "objectGUID" AS objectGUID
    FROM OpenQuery(
        ADSI,
        'SELECT SAMAccountName, mail, objectGUID
        FROM ''LDAP://mydomain.com/OU=blah,OU=blah,OU=blah,DC=mydomain,DC=com''   
        WHERE objectClass=''User''')) 
    AS tbl
INNER JOIN dbo.GroupsDomains gd ON gd.DomainName = SUBSTRING(tbl.Email, CHARINDEX('@', tbl.Email)+1, LEN(tbl.Email)- CHARINDEX('@',tbl.Email))
LEFT JOIN dbo.DefaultSubGroups dsg ON gd.GroupName = dsg.GroupName  
WHERE tbl.objectGUID NOT IN (SELECT UserGUID FROM dbo.Users)
```

GO

Answer (score 2):

I've been reading several papers on this issue. At the end I can't understand how this error arise.

My solution is:
**Put COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT in the join condition...**
...

```
INNER JOIN dbo.GroupsDomains gd ON gd.DomainName = SUBSTRING(tbl.Email, CHARINDEX('@', tbl.Email)+1, 
LEN(tbl.Email)- CHARINDEX('@',tbl.Email))
LEFT JOIN dbo.DefaultSubGroups dsg 

-- Modified this next line:
ON gd.GroupName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = dsg.GroupName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

WHERE tbl.objectGUID NOT IN (SELECT UserGUID FROM dbo.Users)
```